# PHP Forgot Password script not sending email

Tags: php, mysql, forgot-password

I have a forgot password script in PHP below. The idea of the script is to submit the email address, the script then sees if the email address is on the database, then it changes the password and then sends an email with the temporary address to the email that was submitted in the form.

The script appears to change the password and do everything except it does not appear to actually send the email with the temporary password.

It has been a long time since I have used this script (or PHP for that matter) so any help would be appreciated.

```
    <?php # forgot_password.php

    require_once ('./includes/config.inc.php');
    $page_title = 'Forgot Password';
    include ('./includes/header.html'); 

    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { // Handle the form.

       require_once ('database-connection.php');

       if (empty($_POST['user_email'])) { //Validate the email address.
          $uid = FALSE;
          echo 'You forgot to enter your email address!';
       } else {

            $query = "SELECT ID FROM wp_users WHERE user_email='". escape_data($_POST['user_email']) . "'";
            $result = mysql_query ($query)or trigger_error("Query:$query\n<br />MySQL Error: " .mysql_error());
            if (mysql_num_rows($result)== 1) {
            list($uid) = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_NUM);

       } else {
            echo 'This email address is not registered';
            $uid = FALSE;
       }
    }

       if ($uid) { // If everything's OK.
          $p = substr ( md5(uniqid(rand(),1)), 3, 10);
          $query = "UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass=SHA('$p') WHERE ID=$uid";
          $result = mysql_query ($query) or trigger_error("Query: $query\n<br />MySQL Error: " .mysql_error());
          if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {

            $body = "Your password to log into the site has been temporarily changed to '$p'. 
            Please log in using this password and your username. At that time you may change your password to something more familiar.";
            mail($_POST['user_email'], 'Your temporary password.', $body,
            'From:info@website.com.au'); //From email address
            echo 'Your password has been temporarily changed.
            An email from info@website.com.au will be sent to your registered email address with a new, temporary password which you can log in with.
            Once you have logged in with this password, you may change it by clicking on the "Change Password" link at the bottom of your screen.';
            mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.
            include ('./includes/footer.html'); // Include the HTML footer.
            exit();

          } else { //If it did not run OK.
            echo 'Your password could not be changed due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.';
          }
       } else { // Failed the validation test.
          echo '<p><font color="red"size="+1">Please try again.</font></p>';
       }
       mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.
    } // End of the main Submit conditional.

    ?>

    <p>Enter your email address below and your password will be reset.</p>
    <form action="forgot_password.php" method="post">
       <p><b>Email Address:</b> <input type="text"
       name="user_email" size="30" maxlength="40" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['user_email'])) echo $_POST['user_email']; ?>" /></p>
        <div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reset My Password" /></div>
       <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
    </form>

    <?php
    include ('./includes/footer.html');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter your password in DB try to avoid hashing algorithm. SHA is a hashing algorithm not a encrypt algorithm. Please make sure your password field in database must have a big length. I think your SHA() generates a long string. If all things are working fine then please change your mail header to below.

```
$header = "From: noreply@example.com\r\n"; 
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
```

and try

```
mail($to,$from,$message,$header);
```